# Disable open setting menu via status bar

Tags: android, statusbar, android-contextmenu

I'm making android app for the tablet. The user should not be able to do anything else with the tablet. App run as Launcher.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I trying to disable settings via status bar panel:

```
<intent-filter >
  <action android:name="android.settings.SETTINGS" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter >
  <action android:name="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Settings menu can not be open via status bar, but user can go to settings menu via wifi settings on status bar and run another applications or kill/uninstall my app.

Is there a way to disable the settings menu (e.g. by protecting it with a password) or to override it by my application or hide status bar and disabling to expand it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the issue is that the user can go to Settings via WiFi Settings, you could add:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```